# How to implement scrolling over large SVGs while having useful zoom behaviour with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

So I am having a very large SVG image which is very biased towards height (i.e. height is much larger than width). The image width itself is also very large and will not fit in the typical browser window.

I had some success with a simple wrapper like this: `<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll;"><svg>...</svg></div>`.

This works quite well until the width of the image becomes larger than the browser window.
At this point one will want to use browser zoom functionality in order to view some details.
This fails however because the browser will not let you overflow in the x-axis because the image has such a large height (and it will try to keep the aspect-ratio or something).
So the effect is that you get a little bit of zoom in y, but that really does not help.

I also tried some JS trickery but that makes the rendering really slooow.

Ultimately I just want to zoom x and never y. Is that possible somehow?

In a perfect world something like the plot widget from [here](https://www.egui.rs/) would be cool, too (as an example of the scroll effects I would like)

Comment: I’m a little confused what you want the desired zoom behavior to be. When you say you want to “zoom x and never y” what exactly do you mean?